# Pass powershell variable to batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, blat

Here is powershell script

```
$a = get-date -format "MMM-d-yyyy"
Start-Process "D:\Script\send_report.bat"
```

send_report.bat uses blat to send email

```
D:
cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\blat321\full"
blat -s "Daily Report" -i "Our Team" -to member1@team.org,member2@team.org -body "Please see attached." -priority 1 -attach D:\Script\Daily_Report.xlsx
```

How do I insert `$a` into send_report.bat? I would like value of `$a` next to "Daily Report"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd /d "D:\Program Files (x86)\blat321\full"
set "the_date=%~1"
blat -s "Daily Report" -i "Our Team" -to member1@team.org,member2@team.org -body "Please see attached." -priority 1 -attach D:\Script\Daily_Report_%the_date%.xlsx
```

and call the bat like :

```
$a = get-date -format "MMM-d-yyyy"
Start-Process "D:\Script\send_report.bat" $a
```

Answer (score 3):

In your PowerShell script, add `$a` as a parameter to the batch file:

```
Start-Process "D:\Script\send_report.bat" $a
```

In you batch file reference the parameter as `%1`.

```
blat -s "Daily Report %1" -i "Our Team" -to member1@team.org,member2@team.org -body "Please see attached." -priority 1 -attach D:\Script\Daily_Report.xlsx
```